# Adobe Air Writing a File throwing SecurityError: fileWriteResource

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am trying to write into the file and everything was working fine upto the time i used `File.desktopDirectory` but after updating it with `File.applicationDirectory` lots of places i am getting security issue.

So overcome this issue i tried this code

```
                File file = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("urlsList.properties");
                var writeStream:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
                var pathToFile:String = file.nativePath;
                var destination:File = new File (pathToFile);
                writeStream.open(destination, FileMode.WRITE); 
                file.moveTo (destination, true);
                writeStream.close();
```

Now its throwing error at `file.moveTo (destination, true);`

> SecurityError: fileWriteResource  at flash.filesystem::File/moveTo()
> at Demo/addNewUrl()[C:\Users\subodhc\Adobe Flash Builder
> 4.5\Demo\src\Demo.mxml:319]   at Demo/writeFile()[C:\Users\subodhc\Adobe Flash Builder
> 4.5\Demo\src\Demo.mxml:283]   at Demo/__deleteServerConfig023_click()[C:\Users\subodhc\Adobe Flash
> Builder 4.5\Demo\src\Demo.mxml:575]

Comment: AIR protects **File.applicationDirectory** as you might damage or corrupt the the installed app. To avoid that (and the errors) store all your settings into the **File.applicationStorageDirectory**: this location is not only available for writing, it does not require any permissions to do so (I think).